# Image view frame not correctly set by auto layout

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

Simply placing this image in an image view and setting to aspect fit.

[image]

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let image = UIImage(named: "1-landscape")
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        view.addSubview(imageView)
        var collector = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
        collector.appendContentsOf(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0-[imageView]-0-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["imageView": imageView]))
        collector.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        view.addConstraints(collector)
    }
```

At runtime, the height of the view is 50% larger than the height of the image. Why ???

[image]

If we use the old school way of laying our views, there is no problem. Am I forgetting a step with auto layout or something ?

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let image = UIImage(named: "1-landscape.png")!
        let scaleFactor = image.size.height / image.size.width
        let width = view.frame.size.width
        let height = width * scaleFactor
        let size = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
//        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        imageView.frame.size = size
        imageView.center = view.center
        view.addSubview(imageView)
//        var collector = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
//        collector.appendContentsOf(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0-[imageView]-0-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["imageView": imageView]))
//        collector.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
//        view.addConstraints(collector)
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is working but try to load the image in the imageView after setting the scale aspect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forcing the height with a constraint that locks the aspect ratio, did the trick.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let image = UIImage(named: "1-landscape.png")!
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        view.addSubview(imageView)
        var collector = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
        collector.appendContentsOf(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0-[imageView]-0-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["imageView": imageView]))
        collector.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: imageView, attribute: .Width, multiplier: image.size.height / image.size.width, constant: 0))
        collector.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        view.addConstraints(collector)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When the image is scaled, only the size of the image is changed. The size of the imageView doesn't change. You need to change it by finding the Ratio.

Add this

```
    view.layoutIfNeeded()

    let widthRatio = imageView.bounds.size.width / image!.size.width
    let heightRatio = imageView.bounds.size.height / image!.size.height
    let scale =  widthRatio < heightRatio ? widthRatio : heightRatio
    let imageHeight = scale * imageView.image!.size.height

    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .Height , relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: imageHeight))
```

after this line `view.addConstraints(collector)`

Comment: By setting a fixed height like this, the image view won't scale in situations like rotation. See my answer below for to solve this.